# Application starts going nuts after a while

Tags: iphone, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I've recently started using corona SDK and I'm trying to build an app for the iPhone. Now the main idea behind it, is that there are birds flying and you have to shoot them. The birds get a random spot on the screen as their target, and navigate towards it. The app runs fine for about 30 secs - 1 minute, but then suddenly it starts speeding up enormously fast and I don't know why.

And help regarded this is deeply appreciated.

```
display.setDefault("background", 246, 255, 100)
_W = display.contentWidth;
_H = display.contentHeight;
target = {}
birdPosition = {}
print(_W.." ".._H) 
--getting a random location on the screen
local x = math.random(_W)
local y = math.random(_H)

--this checks whether the image will be placed partially off the screen
if x > _W - 42 then
    x = _W - 42
end
if y > _H - 42 then
    y = _H - 42
end

birdPosition[1] = x
birdPosition[2] = y
local equation = 0
--will be used to see whether the movement will be more vertically than horizontally
local moveVertically = false
local bird = display.newImage("images/bird.png", x, y)
--when the bird is touched, it is removed
function bird:touch()
    bird:removeSelf()
end

bird:addEventListener("touch", bird)
--get a new random position
function getNewPosition()
    --loop = 50
    --getting a random next spot to move to + a check
    x = math.random(_W)
    y = math.random(_H)
    if x > _W - 42 then
        x = _W - 42
    end
    if y > _H - 42 then
        y = _H - 42
    end
    --placing the co-ordinates
    target[1] = x
    target[2] = y
    local smallest
    birdPosition[1] = bird.x
    birdPosition[2] = bird.y
    local diffY
    --this check is done so we get a positive equation
    if x > bird.x then
        diffX = x - bird.x
    else
        diffX = bird.x - x
    end
    if y > bird.y then
        diffY = y - bird.y
    else
        diffY = bird.y - y
    end
    --this check is done so that the equation will always be bigger as 1. This also checks
    --whether it will move more vertically than horizontally by putting the boolean true or false
    if diffX >= diffY then
        equation = diffX/diffY
        smallest = diffY
        moveVertically = false
    else
        equation = diffY/diffX
        smallest = diffX
        moveVertically = true
    end

    --print("birdPosition X: "..birdPosition[1].. " birdPosition Y: "..birdPosition[2])
    --print("Target X: " .. target[1].." Target Y: "..target[2])


    --[[
    if for instance diffX = 100 and diffY = 50:
    smallest will be 50, because the move will be vertically and will only have to be executed 50 times
to give it the effect that it flies quick
]]--
    tmr = timer.performWithDelay(10, moveBird, smallest)
end

function moveBird()
    if moveVertically == true then
        if target[1] >= birdPosition[1] then
            bird.x = bird.x + 1
        else 
            bird.x = bird.x - 1
        end
        if target[2] >= birdPosition[2] then
            bird.y = bird.y + equation
        else
            bird.y = bird.y - equation
        end
    else
        if target[1] >= birdPosition[1] then
            bird.x = bird.x + equation
        else 
            bird.x = bird.x - equation
        end
        if target[2] >= birdPosition[2] then
            bird.y = bird.y + 1
        else
            bird.y = bird.y - 1
        end
    end
    --print("Bird X: "..bird.x .. " Bird Y: " .. bird.y)

    --this checks every possibility to get a new position
    if bird.x == target[1] or bird.y == target[2] or bird.y < 0 or bird.x > 640 or bird.x < 0 or bird.y > 960  then
        getNewPosition()
    end
end    

getNewPosition()
```

Comment: My bet is getNewPosition is producing a delay.

Answer (score 0):

One error in `timer.performWithDelay(10, moveBird, smallest)`.

The timer is not called the correct way: the third argument should be the number of iteration (so `1`), and not `smallest`.

See the doc [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html)

Comment: But moveBird makes it only move 1 x or y, therefore the iteration has to be more than 1, else it would only move 1 x or y

Comment: Still, not sure if it should be smallest, but don't see the relevance anyway. Unless there is another delay and the cycles overlap... Is this timer synchronous?

Comment: I mean if movebird hangs(sometimes), the movements could become saturated.

Comment: I think I solved my own problem now. I did change smallest to 1, but in my moveBird function, I changed the check to

    if bird.x == target[1] or bird.y == target[2] or bird.x == 0 or     bird.y == 0 or bird.x > 640 or bird.y > 960 then
      getNewPosition()
     else
      tmr = timer.performWithDelay(10, moveBird, 1)
    
     end

Comment: Yes, so something was hanging and the movements became saturated since the delays were different.

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much for pointing it out and helping a new guy!